# Using partial derivatives to find local max query

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Question:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So $fx = 8x-2xy$ and $fy = 4y-x^2$.

Can anyone advise on the next step to find X and Y values which maximise $f(x,y)$? The total production increase part of the question is confusing me a little.

Comment: It wants you to use a linear approximation $$f(x,y) \approx f(x_0,y_0) + f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$ The total production level increase means that $$x+y = 1.01(x_0+y_0)$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still confused on how that helps determine the values of X and Y to maximise $f(x,y)$. How would I use linear approximation to answer the question? @NinadMunshi

Comment: You tell me, what are your thoughts on the matter? You're too focused on the end goal and not little steps you could take toward that.

Comment: Sure. Plugging in x = 1 and y = 6 into $fx$ and $fy$ yields -4 and 23, respectively. Increasing x and y by 1% each, we can estimate an increase in profit of (-4*0.01) + (23*0.06) through linear approximation. But, this doesn't determine what the largest possible increase in profit is, nor how much to increase X and Y by to achieve the amount. I'm confused on how to get there, if that makes sense? @NinadMunshi